# Variables with both super-subscripts on the same vertical axis

Tags: custom-notation, alignment, subscript

When writing out a variable with both a subscript and a superscript, such as:

```
Subscript[Superscript[f, a], b]
```

one has that the "b" letter is "pushed" to the right compared to the letter "a". I would like instead both scripts to be on the same vertical axis. This seems easy to accomplish, but I do not know how it is done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Subsuperscript`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsuperscript.html):

```
Subsuperscript[f, a, b] // Style[#, 20] &
```

[image]

Keyboard shortcut (thanks: BobHanlon):

[image]

Comment: Great! I knew it was simple. Is there a keyboard shortcut for this? Similar to using Ctrl+_ (or ^)?

Comment: @Patrick.B, i don't know of any keyboard shortcut for Subsuperscript.

Comment: From the `Details` section in the documentation for [`Subsuperscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsuperscript.html): "To enter a subsuperscript in a notebook, use either `ctrl _` to begin a regular subscript or `ctrl ^` to begin a regular superscript. After typing the first script, use `ctrl %` to move to the opposite script position. `ctrl space` moves out of the subscript or superscript position."

Comment: Thank you @BobHanlon.  Will you post it as an answer?

Comment: Feel free to add it to your answer.

Comment: You can use a standard palette to input sub, super and subsuperscripts